# Implicit delegate casting

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting, delegates

I would like to know if there is some way to cast method group, anonymous method or lambda expression to System.Delegate without knowing exact delegate type, like

```
var d = ()=>{};
dynamic d = ()=>{};
Delegate d = ()=>{};
```

I need a way that would work for any method with any parameters and return type and not using reflection.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: A Delegate variable can hold any type of delegate. I don't understand the question.

Comment: All delegates are inherited from `Delegate`, aren't they? `var` just set the type from the initial value set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it is not possible, because a delegate must have a single defined type, but multiple delegates can have the same signature. This makes the delegate type ambiguous - the compiler would have no way of robustly selecting an appropriate type in such a statement. Note that delegate instances of matching-signatures but different *types* are ***not*** interchangeable. For example, is:

```
i => (i % 2) == 0
```

A `Func<int,bool>`, or a `Predicate<int>` ? Or something else? Note that the number of generic arts is irrelevant; an `Action` and `ThreadStart` and `MethodInvoker` are all just void non-generic parameterless delegates.

Additionally, there's an added complication / ambiguity because lambdas can also be compiled to *expression trees*, not just delegates:

```
Func<int, bool> x = i => (i % 2) == 0;
Expression<Func<int, bool>> y = i => (i % 2) == 0;
```

Expression trees are radically different to delegates.